# Making a simple anticheat in C#

Tags: c#, hex, readprocessmemory, anti-cheat

I have tried some ways and followed some tutorials on the web, but nothing helped me yet. What i want to do is a simple anticheat program for my game. All it has to do is to scan programs defined in the source code by name, read it's hex code and search for a string or maybe a hex value. Example: if cheatengine.exe is running, scan this process's hex code. If 0x328934 is found in the hex code, close the program. Is this possible ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But the question is way too broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you didn't find anything...

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

string[] definedPrograms = { "cheatengine.exe", "otherhacktool.exe" };

void stopCheats()
{
    Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process process in processList)
    {
        foreach (string definedProgram in definedPrograms)
        {
            if (Path.GetFileName(process.MainModule.FileName) == definedProgram)
            {
                //Kill the other program
                process.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for reading the process memory and scanning the hex code, you could store the defined hex codes in a 2 dimensional array, but I'm not sure how to get them in the first place.

Also you should probably know that this implementation is not very secure... You could literally change the cheat engine's exe name to something different and the program will not recognize it. I would suggest you at least check for the exe's md5 hash instead of the file name, or even store the entire exe in the program and make it compare the 2 programs' bytes...

I know this did not completely solve the issue, but I hope it points you in the right direction...